# dehumidifier not filling anymore

Tags: dehumidifier

Dehumidifier has been working just fine until the last time I emptied it and replaced the catch bin.  Now the thing just keeps running but not dehumidifying.  The catch bin has no water in it. I cleaned the filter and replaced it.  I tried to change the setting to 45, but after a few seconds it just flips back to 60.

Comment: There could be a sensor that is stuck it would be indicating the catch bin is full. The unit will not function if it “thinks” it will overflow. Post the name brand and model number

Answer (score 1):

It flips back to 60 because that is the humidity it is reading in the space where it is. If it runs and does not produce any water try removing and re-inserting the catch basin to make sure it is the right position. If it still does not produce any water it may be time to replace the unit. If you have to replace the unit, it is probably a good idea to purchase the extended warranty/ insurance policy. My experience with new units is that they do not hold up well. Most usually last only 2-3 years.

Comment: Exactly. My previous unit failed after a year and half. I bought another of a different reputable brand (with the extended warranty, which I usually avoid like the plague), and it also failed after a year and a half. It was sent out for repair and is now working again. With the atrocious quality control on these things lately, pay for the warranty. It's cheaper than buying a new unit every year (not to mention avoiding a massive pollution/material/energy waste).